# Find groups of groups in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to group some records in MySQL based on the following logic:
Each record can belong to two groups (Group1 and/or Group2). They can belong to either 1, 2 or no groups.

What I need is to identify all records that have at least one group in common and create the Final Group.

For example, Record1 and Record3 have "D" in common and Record2 and Record3 have "C" in common, therefore Record1, Record2 and Record3 must be part of the same group (as indicated in the column Final Group).

Any idea of how I can create that Final Group?

Thank you!

PS: 1) Group1 and Group2 contain string values.
PS: 2) It doesn't matter which of the potential values Final Group takes. For example, for Record1, Record2 and Record3, Final Group can be "A", "B", "C" or "D" ... it doesn't matter which of the four, as long as it is one of them.

```
+---------+----------+----------+-------------+  
| Record  |  Group1  |  Group2  | Final Group |  
+---------+----------+----------+-------------+  
| Record1 |     B    |     D    |      B      |  
| Record2 |     A    |     C    |      B      |  
| Record3 |     C    |     D    |      B      |  
| Record4 |     E    |     F    |      E      |  
| Record5 |     F    |     F    |      E      |  
| Record6 |     M    |     N    |      M      |  
| Record7 |     X    |     Y    |      X      |  
+---------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: My bad ... I have corrected the table. They do have the "D" in common now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: You can make this a lot clearer by not using the same names for the final group as for Group1 and Group2. The final group is a different idea.

Comment: I started to write an answer, but I assumed you would be able to model your data in a relational-database-friendly sort of way. Then I re-read the line "Group1 and Group2 contain string values," with in itself isn't fundamentally bad, but I have toowonder if you've been handed the terrible burden of a schema you cannot change. Critical to any good answer, then, is how you store the relationship between record and group, and the query you use to assemble your example results.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r1.Record,
    r1.Group1,
    r1.Group2
FROM
    `records` r1
INNER JOIN
    `records` r2
ON
    r1.Group1 = r2.Group1 OR r1.Group1 = r2.Group2 OR r1.Group2 = r2.Group1 OR r1.Group2 = r2.Group2
ORDER BY
    r1.Record ASC
```

And Calculate the final group programatically